# custom range slider with color marker for a range value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slidetoggle, rangeslider

I have made this range slider. The slider moves as I want. How can I get the value of where the toggle is in this case?

Such as when the toggle is in 1 range, the div should be "The value selected: 1" and so on.

```js
$("#slider").slider({
  value: 50
})
```

```css
#green {
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  /* margin-left: 100px; */
  height: 14px;
}

#blue {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  /* margin-left: 100px; */
  height: 14px;
}

#pink {
  background: pink;
  width: 40%;
  /* margin-left: 100px; */
  height: 14px;
}

#yellow {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  /* margin-left: 100px; */
  height: 14px;
}

#slider {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript"src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<div id="slider">
  <div id="green" class="ui-corner-all">1</div>
  <div id="blue" class="ui-corner-all">2</div>
  <div id="yellow" class="ui-corner-all">3</div>
  <div id="pink" class="ui-corner-all">4</div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/geowaf6s/)

Comment: I suggest reading the JQueryUI Slider documentation:
https://jqueryui.com/slider/

Comment: Read the docs. Check the [Events](https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#events) section. You can hook to the one you need and read the value from the slider to update the DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [API documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/) you can find

```
$( "#slider" ).on( "slidechange", function( event, ui ) {
    let index = Math.ceil($(this).slider("option", "value")/10000*340)-1;
    let selected = $("div#slider").children().eq(index).text();
});
```

Comment: sorry, had to unaccept this answer, the problem with your solution is, it doesn't give the exact value, but it gives the position number. Such as if I add any random no's to the div, it returns same 1,2,3,4. I added random no's to the div such as 8, 9,7,4, When in range of 8 it shound return 8 and so on.

Comment: @pse Adjusted my answer. Hope this helps